# How to check if a file copied successfully? (portable solution) C++

Tags: c++, file, copy, return, portability

How should I modify this code so that it only returns 1 if the file copied successfully?

```
double file_copy(char *source,char *destination)
{
    std::ifstream srce(source,std::ios::binary);
    std::ofstream dest(destination,std::ios::binary);

    dest << srce.rdbuf();

    srce.close();
    dest.close();

    return ???
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Don't return error codes.  Use exceptions instead.

Comment: Does rdbuf() fail silently?

Comment: @Asesh do you mean the "desination" as in the second argument, or "std::ofstream dest" will return null?

Comment: @Asesh: What? No it won't. `destination` will be whatever the caller passed in, and there is nothing in the function which changes it.

Comment: I meant srce.rdbuf will return a nullptr if it fails. Corrected it

Comment: Why return a `double`? I'm not all in on throwing an exception, but maybe. I'd probably return `bool`. `double` makes little sense to me.

Comment: @user4581301 Because GameMaker extensions can't be a bool. Silly, I know...

Comment: API restriction is a good reason.

Comment: @Asesh how do I check if it's a nullptr?

Comment: if(srce.rdbuf()) dest << srce.rdbuf(); else "handle error code goes here"

Comment: You will probably want to validate the size too after copying is done

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I needed! :D

Comment: @Asesh real close. It just needs an extra bit of code to handle a false negative on copying an empty file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++ prior C++17 the following should be a good solution:

- .close() is not necessary, since RAII will take care of that
- correctly and portably handles at least the following cases: missing permissions, missing files, wrong files names, file deleted during write or read, not enough disk space
- there will be no 0 kb output file in case the input file fails or does not exist

The code:

```
double file_copy(const char *source, const char *destination)
{
    std::ifstream srce(source,std::ios::binary);
    if(srce.tellg()<0) return 0.0;

    std::ofstream dest(destination,std::ios::binary);
    if(dest.tellp()<0) return 0.0;

    dest << srce.rdbuf();
    if(srce.tellg()-dest.tellp() != 0) return 0.0;

    return 1.0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This approach is outdated. you have a `<filesystem>` now to do the work in a portable way

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/copy

Comment: <filesystem> doesn't appear to be included with MinGW, it says "no such file or directory". For the kind of stuff that I do, I'd like to avoid downloading includes that aren't shipped with MinGW.

Comment: Looks like filesystem is supported starting with g++5.3 and MinGW still uses 4.4 - There is very similar library in boost - you just need using different namespace http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#copy If boost is also out for you you are locked with old approach.

Comment: @Samuel `<filesystem>` was just added to the standard. Your compiler may not support it yet, and it it does, you'll probably have to set an extra command line argument to enable it. Mingw's GCC support is all over the map, unfortunately due to fragmentation. Some MinGWs support GCC 7. Some way back in the GCC 4s. Most distributions seem to be around 4.8-4.9

Answer (score 0):

One of the universal way of checking file copy is to check CRC32 summs of files. Basically, you need to:

1. read content of the source file
2. count source crc32
3. copy file
4. read content of dest file after copy
5. count dest crc32
6. check two sums.

I would recommentd to use [boost::crc](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/libs/crc/index.html). Because it is portable, you can easilly build it statically and so on, and so on. But if you don't want any additional libs, you can always write your own function. i.e.

```
DWORD crc32_table[256] =
{
    0x00000000, 0x77073096, 0xEE0E612C, 0x990951BA,
    0x076DC419, 0x706AF48F, 0xE963A535, 0x9E6495A3,
    0x0EDB8832, 0x79DCB8A4, 0xE0D5E91E, 0x97D2D988,
    0x09B64C2B, 0x7EB17CBD, 0xE7B82D07, 0x90BF1D91,
    0x1DB71064, 0x6AB020F2, 0xF3B97148, 0x84BE41DE,
    0x1ADAD47D, 0x6DDDE4EB, 0xF4D4B551, 0x83D385C7,
    0x136C9856, 0x646BA8C0, 0xFD62F97A, 0x8A65C9EC,
    0x14015C4F, 0x63066CD9, 0xFA0F3D63, 0x8D080DF5,
    0x3B6E20C8, 0x4C69105E, 0xD56041E4, 0xA2677172,
    0x3C03E4D1, 0x4B04D447, 0xD20D85FD, 0xA50AB56B,
    0x35B5A8FA, 0x42B2986C, 0xDBBBC9D6, 0xACBCF940,
    0x32D86CE3, 0x45DF5C75, 0xDCD60DCF, 0xABD13D59,
    0x26D930AC, 0x51DE003A, 0xC8D75180, 0xBFD06116,
    0x21B4F4B5, 0x56B3C423, 0xCFBA9599, 0xB8BDA50F,
    0x2802B89E, 0x5F058808, 0xC60CD9B2, 0xB10BE924,
    0x2F6F7C87, 0x58684C11, 0xC1611DAB, 0xB6662D3D,

    0x76DC4190, 0x01DB7106, 0x98D220BC, 0xEFD5102A,
    0x71B18589, 0x06B6B51F, 0x9FBFE4A5, 0xE8B8D433,
    0x7807C9A2, 0x0F00F934, 0x9609A88E, 0xE10E9818,
    0x7F6A0DBB, 0x086D3D2D, 0x91646C97, 0xE6635C01,
    0x6B6B51F4, 0x1C6C6162, 0x856530D8, 0xF262004E,
    0x6C0695ED, 0x1B01A57B, 0x8208F4C1, 0xF50FC457,
    0x65B0D9C6, 0x12B7E950, 0x8BBEB8EA, 0xFCB9887C,
    0x62DD1DDF, 0x15DA2D49, 0x8CD37CF3, 0xFBD44C65,
    0x4DB26158, 0x3AB551CE, 0xA3BC0074, 0xD4BB30E2,
    0x4ADFA541, 0x3DD895D7, 0xA4D1C46D, 0xD3D6F4FB,
    0x4369E96A, 0x346ED9FC, 0xAD678846, 0xDA60B8D0,
    0x44042D73, 0x33031DE5, 0xAA0A4C5F, 0xDD0D7CC9,
    0x5005713C, 0x270241AA, 0xBE0B1010, 0xC90C2086,
    0x5768B525, 0x206F85B3, 0xB966D409, 0xCE61E49F,
    0x5EDEF90E, 0x29D9C998, 0xB0D09822, 0xC7D7A8B4,
    0x59B33D17, 0x2EB40D81, 0xB7BD5C3B, 0xC0BA6CAD,

    0xEDB88320, 0x9ABFB3B6, 0x03B6E20C, 0x74B1D29A,
    0xEAD54739, 0x9DD277AF, 0x04DB2615, 0x73DC1683,
    0xE3630B12, 0x94643B84, 0x0D6D6A3E, 0x7A6A5AA8,
    0xE40ECF0B, 0x9309FF9D, 0x0A00AE27, 0x7D079EB1,
    0xF00F9344, 0x8708A3D2, 0x1E01F268, 0x6906C2FE,
    0xF762575D, 0x806567CB, 0x196C3671, 0x6E6B06E7,
    0xFED41B76, 0x89D32BE0, 0x10DA7A5A, 0x67DD4ACC,
    0xF9B9DF6F, 0x8EBEEFF9, 0x17B7BE43, 0x60B08ED5,
    0xD6D6A3E8, 0xA1D1937E, 0x38D8C2C4, 0x4FDFF252,
    0xD1BB67F1, 0xA6BC5767, 0x3FB506DD, 0x48B2364B,
    0xD80D2BDA, 0xAF0A1B4C, 0x36034AF6, 0x41047A60,
    0xDF60EFC3, 0xA867DF55, 0x316E8EEF, 0x4669BE79,
    0xCB61B38C, 0xBC66831A, 0x256FD2A0, 0x5268E236,
    0xCC0C7795, 0xBB0B4703, 0x220216B9, 0x5505262F,
    0xC5BA3BBE, 0xB2BD0B28, 0x2BB45A92, 0x5CB36A04,
    0xC2D7FFA7, 0xB5D0CF31, 0x2CD99E8B, 0x5BDEAE1D,

    0x9B64C2B0, 0xEC63F226, 0x756AA39C, 0x026D930A,
    0x9C0906A9, 0xEB0E363F, 0x72076785, 0x05005713,
    0x95BF4A82, 0xE2B87A14, 0x7BB12BAE, 0x0CB61B38,
    0x92D28E9B, 0xE5D5BE0D, 0x7CDCEFB7, 0x0BDBDF21,
    0x86D3D2D4, 0xF1D4E242, 0x68DDB3F8, 0x1FDA836E,
    0x81BE16CD, 0xF6B9265B, 0x6FB077E1, 0x18B74777,
    0x88085AE6, 0xFF0F6A70, 0x66063BCA, 0x11010B5C,
    0x8F659EFF, 0xF862AE69, 0x616BFFD3, 0x166CCF45,
    0xA00AE278, 0xD70DD2EE, 0x4E048354, 0x3903B3C2,
    0xA7672661, 0xD06016F7, 0x4969474D, 0x3E6E77DB,
    0xAED16A4A, 0xD9D65ADC, 0x40DF0B66, 0x37D83BF0,
    0xA9BCAE53, 0xDEBB9EC5, 0x47B2CF7F, 0x30B5FFE9,
    0xBDBDF21C, 0xCABAC28A, 0x53B39330, 0x24B4A3A6,
    0xBAD03605, 0xCDD70693, 0x54DE5729, 0x23D967BF,
    0xB3667A2E, 0xC4614AB8, 0x5D681B02, 0x2A6F2B94,
    0xB40BBE37, 0xC30C8EA1, 0x5A05DF1B, 0x2D02EF8D,
};    
DWORD GetCrc32(BYTE* bBuff, DWORD dwSizeBuff)
{
    DWORD  dwCrc32 = 0xffffffff;

    while (dwSizeBuff--) {
        dwCrc32 = (dwCrc32 >> 8) ^ crc32_table[(dwCrc32 & 0xFF) ^ *bBuff++];
    }
    return dwCrc32 ^ 0xffffffff;
}
```